# How to unbind prefix commands in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm currently trying to change shortcuts of some packages, and I successfully unbound most of them. However, if I see shortcut description by `C-h b`, keys bound to "Prefix Command" still remains even if I assign nil to it with `define-key`.

Specifically, I was changing my shortcuts of undo-tree package, and even if I put

```
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-x r") nil)
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-x r u") nil)
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-x r U") nil)
```

into init.el, binding description still says `C-x r` is still bound to "Prefix Command".

How can I remove this key from binding list?

Comment: Being listed as a "prefix command" doesn't strike me as a serious problem.  So I presume that you're also seeing some other effect of the remaining binding, and that other effect is the one that really bothers you.  Please specify that other effect.

Comment: @Stefan I just wanted to remove it from binding description, and expected no other effects. Of course it doesn't have any effect on daily usage, but it just bothered me when I open help buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r") nil)`

`C-x r` is a prefix key in the global map, by default.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. But why does emacs help buffer says it is in undo-tree bindings too?

Comment: `C-h b` reflects global bindings too. If you want to see what is in a particular keymap, load[`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) and use `C-h M-k` followed by the keymap variable.

Comment: I tried help-fns+, but it also says `C-x r` is in undo-tree-map. And I think it just shows undo-tree section of `C-h b`.

Comment: OK. I guess that's because that prefix is (also) defined in the keymap, since you have keys in that map that use that prefix.

Comment: Well, I don't think so because there are no other bindings using `C-x r` except `C-x r u` and `C-x r U` in undo-tree-mode, and I unbound those keys in init.el.

Answer (score 0):

Drew's answer is probably the right one, but in some cases you may not know which keymap to use, or you may not want to (or be able to) modify the keymap that holds the binding.  In that case, you can override it in a keymap of higher precedence with, e.g.:

```
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-x r") 'undefined)
```

Comment: I added this line on my init.el, and it did remove "Command Prefix" from description list, but it now overrides other modes' binding about C-x r. Is there any other way of doing this without disturbing other modes?