# In emacs, meta-s is being interpreted as esc-s

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to set a command for C-M-s, however the M-s bit is screwing up. When I try to search for an existing command for the C-M-s keybinding using the describe-key function (C-h k) nothing is registered. When I search for just M-s the buffer registers Esc-s. This only happens with the s key, for example, searching for M-d and C-M-d both work as expected.

Comment: Traditionally, escape is meta.  What is Esc s bound to for you?

Comment: It waits for another entry, I tried a few more keys but didn't find any completions.

Comment: Out of the box, it's a prefix key, like ctrl-X.  I guess that's the reason it behaves different than other keys for you.

Comment: I'm trying to change it with (global-set-key ... ). Is there something else I can use to remove its original command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847624/how-to-unbind-prefix-commands-in-emacs